# Storing and using id_token for all desktop applications

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3

I am new to IdentityServer and I am exploring features that might be used in our environment. We would like to implement SSO for our desktop (WinForms) and web (ASP.NET) applications.
Is it possible to implement a scenario where user authenticates with IdentityServer only once (in first application that he wants to use) and then use an id_token for all WinForms (and web) applications on his PC? Is there a place to store information that current user is already logged in?
It would be great if there is some documentation for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared authentication session between your desktop applications and your web apps.

This is achieved by using the system browser for authentication for both client types.This is also the recommended approach in the "native app spec":

https://tools.ietf.org/wg/oauth/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps/

Comment: I understand in general what you mean by that. So there is strong recommendation to use browser-based authentication because of capability of storing a authentication cookie. Can you please point to some specific examples in IdentityServer samples repository that use this approach? I think I found one: WPF WebView Sample and I would like to start one more sample to test this funcionality: log in from first and then automatically log in from second.